# How to hide dot-files (files with name beginning with fullstop/period) in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hidden-file

In my Windows 10 systems many file names begin with a fullstop/period (like `.ssh`). These files in Unix-like systems are hidden files, how can I hide them all on Windows systems too?

Answer (score 0):

Hidden files are an option in windows, but that is not how you hide these files.  The way to hide them is the command `attrib +h (file)`, and the command to un-hide them is `attrib -h (file)`.

Comment: Thank you... With `attrib +h (file)` I can hide `(file)` but how can I use the `attrib +h` command to hide every file with name beginning with a dot in the system? And is it possibile to give the hidden attribute to every new file created if his name starts with a dot?

Comment: Just use a wildcard, like this: `attrib +h .*`
I can't see a way how you could totally automate hiding every file beginning with a dot when it gets created.